# Bootstrap input-group-addon alignment issue in ASP.NET View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to align an `input-group-addon` correctly in an ASP.NET `View`.

```
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Category</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Hex" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><i></i></div>
                    <input asp-for="Hex" class="form-control" value="" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Hex" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CompanyId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="CompanyId" asp-items="Model.Companies" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

 <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This looks fine in JSFiddle (after adding labels back in). But looks like this when I run the `View`:

[image: Alignment]

If I swap the `input-group-addon` and the `input` the addon floats off to the right.

Could this be something to do with the way a child `View` is rendered by the `_layout` view?

Answer (score 0):

> Could this be something to do with the way a child View is rendered by the _layout view?

Yup. Especially with renderbody.